# How to access values provided as gobject.GParamSpec in GStreamer webrtcbin?

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, gobject

I'm using the GStreamer WebRTC implementation in a Python project. I was trying to obtain status information and was able to enable it on the webrtcbin object like so:

```py
self.webrtc.connect('notify::ice-connection-state', self.on_ice_connection_state)
```

The callback is indeed triggered, but I'm having problems to understand the parameter `p2`.

```
def on_ice_connection_state(self, p1, p2):
    print("ON ICE CONNECTION STATE {} {}".format(p1, p2))
```

The print gives:

```
ON ICE CONNECTION STATE <__gi__.GstWebRTCBin object at 0x112639a00 (GstWebRTCBin at 0x7fe915310220)> <class 'gobject.GParamSpec'>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to determine the current ICE_CONNECTION_STATE from `p2`. Does anybody know, how to achieve this in Python3?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it:

```
print("ON ICE CONNECTION STATE {}".format(self.webrtc.get_property(p2.name)))
```